# State set to true is returning false

Tags: reactjs

I have a data store listener in my React component and inside the callback I'm setting the state. Based off a parameter in the new state I then decide whether to render the component or not.

My code below is achieving this but with unexpected results:

```
shouldComponentUpdate() {
    if (this.props.questionId == 4687760) {
        console.log(!!this.state.didAnswersChange);
    }
    return !!this.state.didAnswersChange;
}

onQuestionStoreChange() {
    let questionStoreData = this.questionStore.get(this.props.questionId);
    if (questionStoreData) {
        if (this.props.questionId == 4687760) {
            console.log(questionStoreData.didAnswersChange || false);
        }
        this.setState({
            didAnswersChange: questionStoreData.didAnswersChange || false
        });
    }
}
```

In the first `console.log` I'm getting `true` printed out. Then for some the `shouldComponentUpdate()` prints out `false`.

Can anybody help me understand how this is possible? I've verified that the `true` being printed out is indeed from the `onQuestionStoreChange()` and the `false` being printed out is from the `shouldComponentUpdate()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per DOC **[shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState):](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate)**

shouldComponentUpdate() is invoked before rendering when new props or state are being received.

shouldComponentUpdate receive new state and props as parameters and this.state will have the prev values only, to check the new state values use newState.key.

> Why this behaviour?

By default this method returns true, to put the check whether we want to render the component for state/props changes, we need both prev values and new values. That's why this.state will have the prev values only in this method.

Write it like this:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState){
    console.log(nextState.didAnswersChange);
}
```